# After transferring Joomla site, I can't install extensions

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I updated a Joomla website for a customer of mine. I did this in XAMPP. Now, when transferring it to the server, I have some problems. I can't install extensions anymore and I get the message:

```
JFolder::create: Infinite loop detected
Warning: Failed to move file!
```

After some reading I found out it's possibly caused by the `log` and `tmp` folder, but I don't know how to rename them to work. (The link to them in the `config.php` file)

`public_html > tmp / log` (both `tmp` and `log` are in the main directory of `public_html`)

How would I set them up to work? And is it definitely this that is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually edit those values using Joomla's back-end.  Go to global configuration settings menu option, one of the text fields is in the Server tab and the other is in the System tab.  If you can, put the full directory path of the server in for the values.

Comment: Tried everything i thought would work. The link that worked before (on the old site) stopped working in the new template with new database.

Comment: Did you change the tmp/ and cache/ directory path fields in the configuration.php file to match the new server?

Comment: Yes i did but the path that worked B4 the update of the joomla site doesnt seem to work anymore (same server same directory) i dont understand it at all lol ..

Comment: Can you confirm the MySQL server is up and accessible with credentials? What do you currently have entered in the configuration.php file for the two directories?

Comment: @user3371474 before changing the tmp and log path make sure the configuration.php is writable. Other wise your changes will never get saved.

Comment: the old path was /var/www/vhosts/webontwerppunt.nl/httpdocs/logs this is an extern domain of the website im working on ... the config file is writable. but now i cant find out the new path

Comment: Hmmm, you could try entering relative directory values of tmp/ and log/and see if that works.  Technically not a best practice but considering worth a try.